# Sub setting times out of time series in R

Tags: r, date, subset

I downloaded stock market data from Yahoo (code below) - for context, at first I tried with `getSymbols(^DJI)` but I got error messages possibly related to Yahoo... different issue.

The point is that once downloaded, and imported into R, I massaged it into a format close enough to a time series to be able to run `chartSeries(DJI)`:

```
require(RCurl)
require(foreign)
x <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RInterested/datasets/gh-pages/%5EDJI.csv")
DJI <- read.csv(text = x, sep =",")
DJI$Date <- as.Date(DJI$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y") # Formatting Date as.Date
rownames(DJI) <- DJI$Date                          # Assigning Date to row names
DJI$Date <- NULL                                   # Removing the Date column
chartSeries(DJI, type="auto", theme=chartTheme('white'))
```

[image]

even if the dataset is not really a time series:

```
> is.ts(DJI)
[1] FALSE
```

The problem comes about when I try to find out the date of, for instance, the minimum closing value of the Dow. I can do something like

```
> DJI[DJI$Close == min(DJI$Close),]
              Open    High     Low   Close Adj.Close   Volume
1985-05-01 1257.18 1262.81 1239.07 1242.05   1242.05 10050000
```

yielding the entire row, including the row name (`1985-05-01`), which is the only part I want. However, if I insist on just getting the actual date, I have to juggle a second dataset containing the dates in one of the columns:

```
require(RCurl)
require(foreign)
x <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RInterested/datasets/gh-pages/%5EDJI.csv")
DJI <- read.csv(text = x, sep =",")

DJI$Date <- as.Date(DJI$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y") # Formatting Date as.Date
rownames(DJI) <- DJI$Date          # Assigning Date to row names
DJI.raw <- DJI                     # Second dataset for future subsetting
DJI$Date <- NULL                   # Removing the Date column
```

which does allow me to run

```
> DJI.raw$Date[DJI.raw$Close == min(DJI.raw$Close)]
[1] "1985-05-01"
```

Further, I don't think that turning the dataset into an `.xts` file would help.

Comment: Please note that when you assign dates to rownames, they turn back to characters. That being said, if you don't want another column in the data.frame containing the dates and you're fine with the dates being character, you can simply do `rownames(DJI)[DJI$Close == min(DJI$Close)]`

Comment: @digEmAll I was under the assumption that a time series requires the row names to be the dates. Isn't this true? Also, I can't run `chartSeries()` if I keep the Date column within the dataset...

Comment: Yes, that's possible (I don't know chartSeries function), but that does not mean you can't have the column in the data.frame anyaway and passing just a columns subset to chartSeries... e.g. `chartSeries(DJI[,-1], type="auto", theme=chartTheme('white'))` (-1 means we're not passing the column at position 1 to chartSeries, of course if Date column is at position 2, you should pass -2 and so on...)

Comment: @digEmAll Is the part about rownames requiring the dates info correct?

Comment: I don't know, I don't even know where chartSeries comes from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear what you want but it sounds like you just want the date? You mention xts is not an option (which would have been runnable)

```
time(as.xts(DJI))[which.min(DJI$Close)] # POSIXct format
# [1] "1985-05-01 EDT"
```

Otherwise a simple `rownames` + `which.min` would get the date for you?

```
as.Date(rownames(DJI)[which.min(DJI$Close)]) # Date format
# [1] "1985-05-01"
```

Comment: I am not familiar with time series, but there are two ideas that are conflicting, and possibly both wrong: 1. Do the rownames of a ts in R need to be the dates? 2. If I convert to ts with `as.xts()` the rownames are erased and defaulted to matrix format.

Comment: When creating a ts object, the frequency of the dates are regular. Creating a ts object with ts() has the arguments for a start date, end date, and the frequency (1 = annual, 4 = qrtrly, 12 = monthly, etc.). Xts objects work differently- they do not assume regular frequency at all, and simply conform values to date slots.